# Слетает вёрстка при задании классу ссылки display: block;

Tags: html, css

Я пытаюсь верстать сайт на Бутстрапе. По макету у меня есть блок с элементами портфолио, при наведении на которые должен быть такой эффект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, когда дошло дело до вёрстки возникла такая проблема.
 Я задал

```
.recent{
    display: block;
}
```

при наведении на картинку, эффект наведения растягивается на всю ширину 9-ти колонок. Подскажите как мне это исправить?

```css
/*MIDDLE BLOCK*/

.middle-white-block{
 background: #fff;
 color: #333333;
}

.flex-block{
 display: flex;
}

.flex-item{
 padding: 25px;
 margin-top: -65px;
 background: #fff;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.flex-item h4{
 font-style: 15px;
 color: #171717;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.grey{
 color: #8e8e8e;
}

.read-more{
 color: #333;
 font-style: 12px;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-top: 17px;
 padding-bottom: 17px;
 background: url(../img/border-line.png) repeat-x 0 0;
 display: block;
}

.read-more:hover{
 background: url(../img/border-line-bot.png) repeat-x 0 100% #888;
 color: #fff;
 transition: 1.5s all;
}

/*PORTFOLIO*/

.works img{
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 23px;
}

.width100{
 width: 30%;
}

.title-recent{
 margin-left: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 19px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 background: url(../img/border-line.png) repeat-x 0 100%;
}

.recent{
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}

.recent:hover .info{
 display: block!important;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}


.info li{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 35px;
 color: #fff;
}

.info li:last-child{
 margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h4 class="title-recent">Recent Work</h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <p class="grey">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, omnis euismod indoctum mel.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, omnis euismod indoctum mel ei, mel erat ancillae eloquent iam id. Movet facete sea cu, deleniti adipiscing id eum. Mel alia consul constituto ex, no his inani reformidans accommoda re. Et eos viderer appellantur, ferri inimicus an ius, ne inermis deseruisse ius.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 works">
          <a href="#" class="recent">
            <img class="width100" src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/12/21/bbdb6df47667ebc0053b692a2a4c2fd6-full.png"alt="image">
            <div class="info hidden">
              <ul>
                <li>201 <br> Views</li>
                <li>90 <br>Likes</li>
                <li> 10 <br> Coments</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="recent">
            <img class="width100" src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/12/21/bbdb6df47667ebc0053b692a2a4c2fd6-full.png" alt="image">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: parent(блок с картинкой) - position: relative; child(блок который показываем при hover) - position: absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #ccc url(http://www.photopoints.com/api/picture/GetThumbnail/5957a9f6-09ba-4ce8-83e0-59c08bfc911a/0);
  border: 1px solid #555;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  transition: opacity .3s linear, background .3s linear;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```